# A subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following topology question. Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. We consider the subset $U_1$ of $\mathbb C^{n+1} \colon U_1=\{a(1,z):a \in \mathbb{C}−\{0\},z \in U\}$. Could someone give me an elementary proof that $U_1$ is open or a counterexample if this not the case.

Comment: What is Cn? you need to explain notation if it's not in common use.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, were did you get stuck?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)#Local_normal_form

Answer (score 1):

A point $(z,w)\in \mathbb C\times \mathbb C^n$ belongs to $U_1$ if and only if $z\ne 0$ and $w/z\in U$. Therefore, $U_1$ is the preimage of $U$ under the map $(z,w)\mapsto w/z$ which is continuous on $(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbb C$.